# Strange compiler warning when precompiling prefix.pch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, llvm

When I want to start my app, I get this:

> clang: error: invalid version number in '-mios-simulator-version-min= '
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

What's going on? When I google this error, I'm getting ZERO. This seems to be a very strange failure. 
Please apologize, that I can't give more information. It's because I'm completely clueless.
Help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution: 
.xcodeproj > General > Deployment Target ----> **was empty!**

This is not allowed.

Comment: I had an issue even if mine was NOT empty, it was set as 10.0, but still gave me the above error. I simply deleted that and wrote 10.0 again and it started to work! Try deleting it and rewriting it if you are having problems even if it is not empty.

Comment: u saved my life!

Comment: Mine had a tiny little space: "9.0 ". I love invisible characters :)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and/or quitting and relaunching Xcode. I've had various odd problems  with Xcode that require one or the other of those things.

Comment: I did "clean build folder..." and relaunched Xcode. unfortunately this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is a space after 8.0 like "8.0 ". When I remove space and re-build error disappears.